# Backbone.js - Saving individual item in collection - what it the proper REST approach?

Tags: rest, backbone.js

I have a model (`Parent`) which contains a collection of type `Child`

I'm fetching the model in this way:

```
GET /parent/:parentId
```

My question is, what it the standard way to update an *individual* child?  Should the URL look something like?:

```
PUT /parent/:parentId/child/:childId
```

Comment: That's the way to do it if you server end uses nested resources. Meaning, say, you have a child with ID 123 and a Project_id abc, and if you DO use nested resources, you can never get said child simply by GET /child/123, you have to do project/abc/child/123; if you don't use nested resources, then you can arrive at /child/123 directly. So what is your setup on the server? - By the way, I think if you can, you should pluralize your resource names parents, children.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are doing it right. Have a look at the rails guide http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#crud-verbs-and-actions it contains some examples.

You can also flatten all resources. So the child is accessed from /child/:id like the parent. This way the child can be added to multiple objects. For example an address can be associated to a contact or a company.